# Creating a new "Member" in one step

Tags: civimember, contacts, contributions, user

If you "become a member" by going through the normal route of "joining" through the website front-end -- using a CiviCRM profile and requiring the creation of a Joomla (in my case) account -- it is an easy one step process. However, my organization has a lot of older members who join through the mail or in person.

This means that you have to:
(1) Create a CiviCRM "Contact"
(2) Create a CiviCRM "Membership"
(3) Create a CiviCRM "Contribution" and
(4) Create a Joomla user that is connected to the CiviCRM "Contact".

That is a cumbersome four step process that is being handled in one go if you join through the website front-end. In addition, you cannot create a Profile form that has more than one "category" in it, which means you cannot create a profile form so that somebody already logged in can create a new member, accomplishing all of these tasks in one form, or on one page.

I have thought to myself, "Surely somebody out there has faced this problem and solved it," but after nearly 6 months of searching the web, reading the CiviCRM wiki, searching the old boards and the new Stack Exchange board, I can't even find anybody discussing it.

Does somebody have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you go to the contribution page path with &cid=0 appended on the path, so that as an admin you fill in the Membership form as if you were logged out, and therefore do steps 1, 2 and 4 (at least) on one screen.

Comment: any of the below answers help you Clifton - StackExchang thrives on feedback

Answer (score 1):

It should never be a 4 step process as the contribution and membership records are created at the same time. When you sign someone up for a membership offline via **Add Membership** on the membership tab of their contact record you tick the "Record Membership Payment" box and enter the payment during the membership creation or, if it is a credit card payment you choose **Submit Credit card membership** and the details for recording the payment are visible from the beginning.

You can get it down to 2 steps if it is a credit card payment and you make use of the "not you or want to do this for another person" feature at the top of the **online** sign up page.(The only step to do separately would be creating the onnected Joomla user.)

If you were using Drupal and the payment was by Credit card you could do it in one step if you used CiviRules to tag the contact when it was created and then implemented the steps outlined in [Creating Drupal users made easy](https://civicrm.org/blogs/petednz/creating-drupal-users-made-easy-single-or-multiple-contacts-civi-imports-and-webforms) .

However, I note that you are using Joomla.  I don't use Joomla and don't know if anyone has created a similar method for creating Joomla users by tagging civicrm contacts.

Answer (score 0):

As an admin you can visit the contribution page path with &cid=0 appended on the path, that way the admin can fill in the Membership form as if you were logged out, and therefore do steps 1, 2 and 4 (at least) on one screen

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using fabrik. I'm currently working on a similar project.

I have created a list using civicrm_contact table and then on the form submission i write own custom code to manually insert data to civi tables. Meantime it creates a Joomla account and add data to relevant tables. If you want to go down this route let me know. I can provide some help